# Can Someone Help me in writing DW code for below Java Code

Tags: dataweave

Here is the java version, can someone help me in getting this done in mulesoft dw version. Below works with java not sure how this can be done using dataweave 2

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static String convertSfId(String idSalesforce) {
        if(idSalesforce.length() == 18){

            return idSalesforce;
        }
        else if(idSalesforce.length() != 15){

            return null;
        }
        else{
            String suffix = "";
            String idOut= "";
            String InChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345";
            for(Integer i = 0; i<3; i++){
                Integer flags = 0;
                for(Integer j = 0; j<5; j++){
                    String c = idSalesforce.substring(i*5+j, i*5+j+1);
                    if((c.compareTo("A")>=0) && (c.compareTo("Z")<=0)){
                        flags += 1 << j;
                    }
                }
                suffix = suffix + InChars.substring(flags, flags+1);
            }
            idOut = idSalesforce + suffix;

            return idOut;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really how StackOverflow works.  Would be more beneficial for you to attempt to learn DataWeave instead of continuously asking others to do it for you. This is the theme of all of your questions.  Take a crack at it and come back with what you've tried and we'll give you a hand.

Comment: no worries. i figured how to invoke this java method using dataweave . Cheers

Comment: Nice start to the solution.  I'm taking a look at it.  I'm wondering what it is you're trying to do.  This looks like a convoluted way of doing something that may be fairly simple.  Just a hunch.  Can you describe what you're trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: In salesforce for some particular records we are getting 15 char id , i believe in lightning it is 18char. so when we get 15char  we need to convert it to 18char.  I would still like to see how it can be done in dw.

Comment: What is the logic for adding those 3 chars at the end of the string ? is it the convoluted nested for loops with a lexicographic comparison?

Comment: I posted the dataweave that will get you what you want.  Seems like a convoluted way of adding three characters.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var id="dddddfe001hhEEE"
var alphaNums = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345"

fun convertSfId(data)= 
    if(sizeOf(data) == 18)  data
    else if(sizeOf(data) != 15)  null
    else outerLoop()

fun outerLoop() = [0,1,2] reduce (oIndex, acc=id) -> (acc ++ alphaNums[innerLoop(oIndex)])
fun innerLoop(oIndex) = [0,1,2,3,4] reduce (iIndex, acc=0) -> innerAcc(oIndex, iIndex, acc)

fun innerAcc(oIndex, iIndex, acc) =
    if(isUpperCase(id[(oIndex*5 + iIndex)])) 
        acc + (2 pow iIndex) 
    else 
        acc
---
convertSfId(id)
```

Comment: I think this breaks if the string format changes a bit. For e.g. for "001700000156ERT" this would break.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I added the parens on this line to resolve that bug acc + (2 pow iIndex)

Answer (score 0):

@Dale Thanks for your comment. I did gave a try and came upto below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var id="001700000156M2c"

var test=id [0 to 5]
fun convertSfId(data)= 
if(sizeOf(data) == 18)  data
    else if(sizeOf(data) != 15)  null
    else [0 to 3] map(data,i) ->{
       ( [0 to 5]  map(data,j)  ->  using(c=data [(i*5+j) to (i*5+j+1)] ){
        // didn’t find compare strings lexicographically
    // and also in java we can create variables in between not sure how to do that in dw 
    // for example in java flags += 1 << j; here am updating flags 

        })
    } 

---
convertSfId(id)
```

Comment: Regarding variables, if you use a `do` scope you can define variables inside of it. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_do (this is also recommended instead of `using`)

Comment: Can you add this to your question instead of posting it as an answer?  Thanks

Comment: Stop using `using ()` and start using `do {}`.  `using` does not create localized declarations as it was intended, it creates variables that are visible to the script as whole (i.e. as if they were defined above the `---`).